# Why is this Android Instrumentation Test invoking activity onCreate twice?

Tags: android, mocking, kotlin, mockwebserver

I have this test class:

```
class InspirationalQuoteInstrumentedTest {

    private lateinit var server: MockWebServer

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val mActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<InspirationalQuoteActivity> = ActivityTestRule(InspirationalQuoteActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        server = MockWebServer()
        server.start()
        Constants.BASE_URL = server.url("/").toString()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        server.shutdown()
    }

    @Test
    fun ensureTheQuoteOfTheDayIsDisplayed() {
        println("Base URL: ${Constants.BASE_URL}")
        Log.e(TAG,"Base URL: ${Constants.BASE_URL}")
        val response200 = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("200.json").readText()
        val jsonResponse = JSONObject(response200)
        val expectedQuote = jsonResponse
                .getJSONObject("contents")
                .getJSONArray("quotes")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("quote")
        server.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(response200))

        val intent = Intent()
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent)

        onView(withId(R.id.inspirationalQuote))
                .check(matches(withText(expectedQuote)))
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = InspirationalQuoteInstrumentedTest::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

And I have this activity:

```
class InspirationalQuoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var quoteService: QuoteOfTheDayService
    private var quote: String = ""
    private var author: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspirational_quote)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.inspirationalQuote) as TextView

        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        textView.text = getQuoteOfTheDay()
    }

    private fun getQuoteOfTheDay(): String {
        quoteService = QuoteOfTheDayService()
        val qod = quoteService.getQuoteOfTheDay()
        val response = qod.execute()
        Log.e(TAG, "Response: $response")
        response?.let {
            quote = response.body()!!.contents.quotes[0].quote
            author = response.body()!!.contents.quotes[0].author
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Expected Quote: $quote")
        return quote
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = InspirationalQuoteActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

When I run my test `getQuoteOfTheDay()` gets executed twice. What gives? The issue is that I'm trying to mock out an api call which looks like it's working ask expected, however there is another log that I'm not sure where it's coming from. For reference, here is the out put in logcat

```
Response: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://quotes.rest/qod}
Expected Quote: Let us think the unthinkable, let us do the undoable, let us prepare to grapple with the ineffable itself, and see if we may not eff it after all.
Response: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://localhost:37290/qod}
Expected Quote: Winning is nice if you don't lose your integrity in the process.
```

As you can see, I hit `https://quotes.rest/qod` once, and then I hit my mock server after that.

Comment: Can you add the code of ActivityTestRule? Maybe you are launching the activity there as well

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to pass a few arguments to the constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed some arguments in the constructor... Doh.

Changing

```
ActivityTestRule(InspirationalQuoteActivity::class.java)
```

to

```
ActivityTestRule(InspirationalQuoteActivity::class.java, false, false)
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are launching your activity with the intentTestRule 
`IntentsTestRule<>(InspirationalQuoteActivity.class, false, true);`

The third parameter is `launchActivity`, you must set it as false